How to get data of leads center of meta business suite through API
I am using meta business suite leads center screen to manage potential candidates.
But I want to write a tool to export the information on the screen of each candidate such as label, Assigned to, Stage.. to save to a separate database system.
Leads center image
I also know the api below can get basic information, but it seems to need ad_id, form_id. Although I am not using any ad at the moment. Can it be solved using webhook?
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/retrieving

I think you can't get all data in leads center. The retrieving leads api just get leads data by action through ads.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
